# LAPTOP battery draining faster without overheating issue

Tags: 14.04, ati, battery

I have a hp laptop with an AMD graphics card and I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside my window 8.1. Under Ubuntu the laptop is quiet silent and smooth (no overheating) but the battery is draining very fast.
It only last for one hour max.
In windows it lasts for ~2.5 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use powertop (`sudo powertop`) to see your biggest energy consumers, and to check (under "Tunables") if laptop-mode-tools/TLP are working properly - most parameters are supposed to switch to "Good" once the laptop is unplugged.

Some minor parameters (like VM writeback timeout, swappiness etc.) which are not auto-adjusted can be adjusted manually. Google will help you to find out how.

However, if your laptop has AMD/Nvidia graphics, power drainage is probably caused by the opensource X graphic driver. In which case, as much as we all like opensource, you have no option but to install proprietary video drivers (fglrx/bumblebee respectively). You will easily find the how-to's on the web.

Answer (score 0):

There are various tweaks that you can apply to your laptop to save battery power, but many of them depend on the hardware, Linux distribution, some are outdated or too hard to apply for regular users and so on. TLP is an advanced power management command line tool for Linux that tries to apply these settings / tweaks for you automatically, depending on your Linux distribution and hardware.

For more info on the same, you may refer [TLP page](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html).

Hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

I will usually edit my /etc/fstab file to include "noatime" on my partitions. This will disable the recording of last access time on files/folders, so less writes to your HDD/SSD and thus less battery used. I also found using an SSD will get you some extra battery time due to the lack of physical moving parts within.