# Battery drains fast in Ubuntu14.04LTS. Screen goes out when switched to NVidia proprietary driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, power-management, battery

I am facing power issues on my  HP Pavilion 15 - p073tx laptop running on Ubuntu 14.04LTS. The battery drains much faster as compared to when I run Windows(I have a dual boot). One solution I found is that the X.org drivers are taking a lot of power: [LAPTOP battery draining faster without overheating issue [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/a/500710/527481)

Following this I tried changing my driver to NVidia proprietary drivers. However, after doing this, my laptop screen went off on the next restart and did not turn on, but the laptop was running. This also happened on a Lenovo laptop. The only solution to this was a fresh Ubuntu installation, which was so painful. 
[image: Proprietary Graphics Drivers Ubuntu]

I had selected the top-most option, `352.63 from nvidia-352(proprietary, tested)`. Now I want to save power but not at the cost of a lost display. Is there any permanent fix to this power problem?